# Download is not permitted from Jupyter notebook running on the GCP server

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook running on the GCP server by local Chrome, I want to download a file from Jupyter notebook but it has been denied. While I can upload files by Jupyter notebook-Unploadfiles. What should I do to get permission?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4yQj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that I was using jupyter notebook by http://localhost:8080/lab, in the lab mode I can't download anything. Then I change it into http://localhost:8080/tree, in this mode everything is normal as a local server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a issue for Chrome users and for version 5.6.7 of Jupyter Notebook. 
There is a workaround to download files from Jupyter Notebook using Firefox.

[Here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/download-of-file-from-jupyterlab-fails/628) you can see that it's a issue to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I find the solution.